# Prepend results from "fd" with "~/" for fzf. Sed complains `no matches found`

Tags: shell, zsh, fixed, fzf

I am trying to create a function for fzf in zsh.

I want to list all directories and files under my home folder in fzf, prepend these with "~/", and then ultimately save my choice in a variable.

So far I have this:

`myVar=$(fd -t d -t f . ~ | xargs realpath --relative-to=$HOME | sed s/^/~\// | fzf)`

When I just run the code in the shell, it does what I want (apart from complaining `xargs: unmatched single quote;...`.

However, when I put it in a function and source the file containing it, sed complains about `no matches found: s/^/~//`

How can I make the function behave the same as when the code is run in the interactive shell? And what is the reason for the different behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zsh` is trying to perform pathname generation on the argument before passing the result to `sed`. By default, `zsh` treats a non-matching pattern as an error, rather than leaving it as a literal string like `bash` does by default.

The solution is to simply quote what you want `zsh` to leave alone.

```
myVar=$(fd -t d -t f . ~ | xargs realpath --relative-to=$HOME | sed "s/^/~\//" | fzf)
```

Comment: Thank you!
Could you clarify this:
"...zsh treats a non-matching pattern as an error..."
This means that zsh tries to interperet `s/^/~//` as something other than a string?

Comment: You appear to have the `extendedglob` option set, so the `^` in the `sed` command makes that word a pattern, which `zsh` tries to expand. There are lots of ways for that expansion to fail, the most obvious one probably being that there is no directly named `s` in the current working directory.